# MySQL JOIN only returns first match

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to use this join to return multiple rows of User ID's where they are found to be in a list of recipients from a specific row in another table.

```
SELECT a.`USER_ID`
FROM Users a
INNER JOIN Lists b ON a.`USER_ID` = b.`RECIP`
WHERE a.`PARENT` = '1'
AND b.`LIST_ID` = '210'
```

The query above should return 5 rows as there are 5 matches in `RECIP`, but I'm only seeing 1 result which is the first match in `RECIP`

In the table 'Lists', row LIST_ID '210' RECIP contains '22,33,40,42,45'
As such, I hoped that the query would return 5 rows from the table 'Users' as all of those USER_ID's exist:

USER_ID 22

USER_ID 33

USER_ID 40

USER_ID 42

USER_ID 45

But I only get one result:

USER_ID 22

I've tried a number of things (SELECT DISTINCT..., GROUP BY a.ID) but I'm making no progress. To be honest I'm still trying to get my head around joins.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: This `b.ID = '210'` is the predicate that restricts matching records from `Lists` table.

Comment: Yeah, I think you wanted to filter on an ID in `a` not `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `recip` field contains the numbers in a list as `'22,33,40,42,45'`. If this string is matched to a number in `a.USER_ID = b.RECIP`, then the string will be evaluated as number 22 because comma is not part of a valid number expression in mysql, so the mysql stops evaluating the string at the first occurance of a comma.

The best solution would be to normalise your data structure and store each value within `recip` in its own record.

The quick solution is to use [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in the join expression:

```
SELECT a.`USER_ID`
FROM Users a
INNER JOIN Lists b ON find_in_set(a.`USER_ID`,b.`RECIP`)>0
WHERE a.`PARENT` = '1'
AND b.`LIST_ID` = '210'
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. Works perfectly on smaller `RECIP` values but I'll need to devise a more effecient solution as some of the RECIP lists contain over 10,000 ID's at the moment

Comment: As said, the best solution would be to normalise your data structure. My guess is that you followed the quick solution.

Comment: Temporarily yes. But I promise I will normalise the data structure for long term benefits! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering on only one row in your second table because of this:

```
AND b.`ID` = '210'
```

One of the following should work , depending on your data, which you haven't show anything:

```
SELECT a.`ID`
FROM Users a
INNER JOIN Lists b ON a.`ID` = b.`RECIP`
WHERE a.`PARENT` = '1'
```

or

```
SELECT a.`ID`
FROM Users a
LEFT JOIN Lists b ON a.`ID` = b.`RECIP`
WHERE a.`PARENT` = '1'
```